# How to mock Dapper using SQL Connection

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, moq, dapper

I am trying to write the unit test cases for the repositories. I am struggling to mock the dapper using SQL connection.

My method:

```
public IEnumerable<TestModal> TestMethod(int id)
{
    var spName = "sp_Test";
    var spParams = new
        {
            ID= id
        };

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDB")))
    {
        connection.Open();
        return connection.Query<TestModal>(spName, spParams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

I am trying to write the unit test case for the above method.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClassTests
{
    private Mock<IConfiguration> _mockConfiguration;
    private Mock<SqlConnection> _mockSqlCOnnection;
    private ITestRepository _testRepository;
    
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockConfiguration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        _mockSqlCOnnection = new Mock<SqlConnection>();            
        _testRepository= new TestRepository(_mockConfiguration.Object);
    }
   
    [Test]
    public void TestMethodTest()
    {           
        _mockSqlCOnnection.SetupDapper(x => x.Query<TestModal>(It.IsAny<string>(), null, null, true, null, null)).Returns(fakeData);

        var result = _testRepository.TestMethod(10);

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count(), fakeData.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: What do you mean to test? There is no testable logic in your method, unit-testable, that is. You need to do an integration test with an actual database connection, if you mean to get any value.

Comment: Mocking concrete classes is a code smell. You probably want to mock IDbConnection rather than SqlConnection, and then restructure your code so that TestMethod can get an instanced IDbConnection cleanly.

Comment: I'd rather go with a real db and use sth like https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn or https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed (I'm authoring the latter). Mocks tend to make your tests fragile in general, so it's better imo to use stubs, when test double is needed to isolate some component. See an article about issues of mocks https://medium.com/javascript-scene/mocking-is-a-code-smell-944a70c90a6a

Answer (score -3):

**You should not be mocking your database for unit testing.**

Databases are very complex things, meaning your tests will provide little to no value if you're not using an actual database, no matter how well you mock it.

Depending on how complex your repository logic is you might want to use either a lighter database provider, like SQLite, LocalDb, etc. or an actual database like a local SQLServer.

Obviously you'd get the most accurate results if you use the same database as your production environment.

For examples on how unit testing works with SQLite you can have a look at Microsoft's [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite) about unit testing with SQLite and InMemory databases. The article uses EF Core, but you should be able to extrapolate to use the same approach with Dapper.

For more information on unit-testing with real databases, you can read Jimmy Bogard's [article](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/02/19/reliable-database-tests-with-respawn/) on unit-testing with [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn).

Comment: This isn't particularly helpful. There can be some benefits to mocking code that is responsible for communicating with a DB (such as ensuring the proper stored procedure is called, etc.) This can done alongside more rigorous testing methods beyond unit testing (integration testing, etc).

Comment: There is very little value in such tests since your actual persistence layer might not even support stored procedures. You'd be effectively testing your mocks. Besides the stored procedure might be missing on the actual server where the application might be deployed, for example removed after a migration was applied. Your test would be giving you false positives, and you'd have no idea your code will fail until it reaches production. Fact is no matter how well you mock the database you would still not get the actual behavior.

Comment: Correct, you don't want to test your database but you are testing the mapping from the data to your entity model. Some sort of testing here has value.

Comment: Agreeing with @Bronumski here. These type of tests shouldn't be about testing the db .. but it's for code that -calls- the db. Tests for _that code_ shouldn't hit the db. So we can mock out the db-call. And no .. IRepository isn't always the design pattern to follow, which is usually the other answer people say with abstracting away db calls.

Comment: To properly test the data mapping, you'll have to simulate the results coming from the database, which in most cases is complicated and error prone. And even if you succeed to fake the results coming from the integration layer you're still testing your fakes, which is useless. If/when the actual behavior of the database will change you'll be getting false positives in your tests.
The part that is using the integration layer can very well be tested using a fake or a mock of the repository, query object or any other pattern used.

Comment: You can make that argument about any type of mocking. I could mock out the response from an API call that can change, I could switch the method that I am calling on an api and not update the test. Everything has value when used correctly. Your comment about only testing your fakes is incorrect. You are testing the mapping of the data coming out of your fake. A fake/mock/stub/substitution is only ever based on what you know to be true at the time. There are also lots of ways to remove or minimise any schematic disconnects between your real data structure and the one you use in your tests.

Comment: Yes this argument can be made about any type of mocking of integration level services. For instance if you need to create a HttpClient add an authentication token and open a connection and then read the result from a HttpResponse stream, then I would argue that mocking the HttpClient is also useless. If you are not covering it with integration tests and just mocking then you have false positive tests and if you are then you already covered the mapping.